# How can I call AppController's method based on database tables?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to make CRUD of all database tables in APP controller instead of all CRUD related functions in inherited controllers.

For example:

```
www.example.com/settings/edit/1
www.example.com/users/edit/1
www.example.com/news/edit/1
```

I want to shift this Edit functionality to App controller.

In that case, because of all controllers (settings, users, news) are inherited from APP so they can access AppController's method EDIT.

I want to access this without creating a file of inherited controller.

I am trying with this routes.

```
$routes->connect('/:table/edit/:recordId', ['controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'edit'],['pass' => ['table', 'id'], 'id' => '\d+']);
```

But its showing error

```
Missing argument 2 for App\Controller\AppController::edit()
```

while in controller I wrote :

```
public function edit($table, $recordId){
}
```

Any help regarding this will be really appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: You are trying the opposite of good MVC practice? A good place to make sharing "controller" methods are components.  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html

Comment: Hmmmmmm I agree with you. So you are suggesting that these common functions like edit/delete/add/list should be in component and I should load component and call these functions ... Am I right ?

Comment: yes, create components with all shared methods.

Comment: OK let me try with that. 
Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: try this plugin https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud

Comment: @NaveedRamzan You used `recordId` and `id` in `connect`, try using same name in both places.

Comment: @Holt : Thanks for the correction. But it doesn't work. Now trying with component thing.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan You said you want to do something without  having to create multiple controllers, the whole purpose of components is to be **shared among controllers**, so this clearly goes in the opposite direction as what you want to do.

Comment: OK right. Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: @Salines : Hi, I have updated my architecture and now I made a component named CRUD. But for using component's method I need to call controller which will be something like 

$routes->connect('/edit/:table/:id', ['controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'edit'], ['table' => '[a-z+]', 'id' => '[0-9+]']);

Now kindly guide me that why its not mapping. it says EDITCONTROLLER should be created while as per routing, it should go to App controller -> edit method ? is not ?

Comment: @NaveedRamzan ask plugin authors for support or here http://discourse.cakephp.org/

Comment: @Salines : I updated like $routes->connect('/edit/*', ['controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'edit']); and in method(passed both parameters)